# Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred, using clipShape for Image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following a tutorial about Swift UI and I'm new with it, I tried the following code but got an error that I don't understand.

The code is working fine on the tutorial and it looks like new videos that is not that old, here is the code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
//            Color(red: 1.00, green: 0.89, blue: 0.00)
//                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Image("pp")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: CGFloat(150.0), height: CGFloat(150.0))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(
                        Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: CGFloat(5.0))
                    )
                Text("John Doe")
                    .font(Font.custom("AdventPro-Regular", size: 40))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Text("Web & iOS Developer")
                    .font(.Font.custom("AdventPro-Regular",size: 25))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
.font(.Font.custom("AdventPro-Regular",size: 25)) // << .Font is error
```

use

```
.font(Font.custom("AdventPro-Regular",size: 25))
```

Compiler sometimes cannot detect correct place of error for SwiftUI code, to find real place of error in your view builder, try to comment-out parts of code - that would help.